# How to list all recipts in a block using web3js?

Tags: web3js, web3j

I'm trying to list all transactions and their receipts from given block. Transactions get be included in the result of GetBlockByNumber function but I have found no option to include receipts.

I can ask for each receipt in a block one-by-one but this is terribly inefficient.

Is there another way to get all transactions?

Comment: This still remains a big problem. I wish there was a way to get **all** receipts for all transactions in a block. You can get the full transactions in a block (not only their hashes) using the `full_transactions` flag (at least using `web3.py`) but you **still** need to query for the receipts 1-by-1 for each transaction. This is killing my application.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing it from the web3 console, you can script this.

Simple as:

```
eth.getBlock(<BLOCKNR>).transactions.forEach(function(tx) {eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx);})
```

Comment: I'm going through remote rpc

Comment: Then you can script it in the same way through multiple JSON RPC calls.

Comment: I'm on a light node, which it seems can't even look up receipts by transaction hash, despite dumping all historical blocks fine.